# retrieving value that i just input

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

hi im pretty new in laravel and i stumble upon some trouble passing my value to my input, heres the following code :

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate([
                'username' => $request->input('username'),
                'password' => $hasher->make($request->input('password')),
                'costumer_id' => $request->input('costumer_id'),
                'role_id' => $request->input('role_id')
                ]);

$costumer= Costumer::updateOrCreate([
                'id' => $user->costumer_id,
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
                'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            ]);

$register = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
```

I want to pass the costumer_id that I just input to my id in customer table but I got an error saying `Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "users_costumers_id_foreign"`

can someone help me how do I do that? thanks in advance

Comment: First make the `Costumer` and then relate it with user. This is how foreign key works. Meanwhile, your relation of costumer and user seems quite irrational.

Comment: i did all of that sir

Comment: Please read the following documentation and use laravel relations accordingly: [Eloquent Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). This should help.

Comment: silly me, i put the $costumer above the user and now its working. thank you sir

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant in first comment. Happy it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate([
                'username' => $request->input('username'),
                'password' => $hasher->make($request->input('password')),
                'costumer_id' => $request->input('costumer_id'),
                'role_id' => $request->input('role_id')
                ]);

if($user){
 $costumer= Costumer::updateOrCreate([
                'id' => $user->costumer_id,
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'first_name' => $request->input('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
                'phone_number' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            ]);
}


$register = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
```

or you can use **transaction** . It is better option.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions